# Update through looking up a value and update the corresponding value

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with different item codes and prices. I want to update them as soon as a new price list comes in. Initially I have made one sheet with detailed item codes and in front, I have prices from all the vendors in different columns.

I have connected the each vendor value with simple `=` formula to another sheet, but when it comes to update, I have to manually look for each item code and see if the price is changed or not and then update it.

I am thinking of having an formula so the when it refers to the other sheet looks up the itemcode and then its price and if it is changed, update it automatically.

So in summary `E2` should be updated when I update the Vendor Price List.

Comment: see my updated answer. Btw, if you have some questions, write them below my answer as comments

Answer (score 1):

Use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) formula.

Let your data with list codes be in `Sheet2` colunm `A` and corrsponding values in `Sheet2` colunm `B`, and let you have some code in `Sheet1` cell `A1` and you want to find corresponding value for this code. Then you can use following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0)
```

Here is [**test workbook**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rywnrfcvgwfx6x/simoco1.xlsx).